# PHP - Read file on foreign server?

Tags: php

I need to read a file on a foreign server.

**Apart from cURL and `file_get_contents()` are there any other ways to read the file using PHP?**

This needs to be deployed on a variety of servers and some servers we are deploying to are really cheap shared hosts. These often have configurations that disable either or both of these methods.

The file I need to get is an XML file if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target is an XML file, you could try using PHP's DOM implementation.  For example:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp');
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a raw socket http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

or call out to the shell and use curl or wget from there